# How to create an array from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Given the following:

```
var example = [{
  "logged": {
    "status": 0,
    "status_name": "Logged",
    "hours": 23 // to the hours array
  },
  "pending": {
    "status": 3,
    "status_name": "Pending",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 0,
      "count": 0
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 6, // to the hours array
      "count": 1
    }
  },
  "denied": {
    "status": 4,
    "status_name": "Denied",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 0,
      "count": 0
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 0, // to the hours array
      "count": 0
    }
  },
  "approved": {
    "status": 2,
    "status_name": "Approved",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 4.5,
      "count": 1
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 0, // to the hours array
      "count": 0
    }
  }
}];
```

How would I construct two (2) arrays like such:

```
var statusNames = ["Logged", "Pending", "Denied", "Approved"];
var hours = [23, 6, 0, 0];
```

I can infer how to get the rest if the values from the solution.

Comment: Are there more entries in the array or only 1?

Comment: So, you want one array that has all the keys, and another that has all values for a particular key - one which can be arbitrarily nested - is that correct?

Comment: No simple way I guess, you will need to loop through each of those elements and add it to the array

Comment: Just a conventional use case for `Array#map`... What efforts did you put ?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee I don't think it's that hard. It seems to me that the first task is trivial, the second is merely easy. There are already built in ways to interact in an array to produce these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)  method for getting all object property name array and then generate the result arrays using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
// array for storing the hours value
var hours = [];
// genarte the statusName array
var statusNames = Object.keys(example[0]) // get object keys
            // iterate over key value          
            .map(function(k) {
                // get the value of hour and push it to hours array
                // get `hours` property if defined or get hours property
                // of nested object verification or push 0
                hours.push(example[0][k].hours || example[0][k].verification.hours || 0); 
                // get the status name and return
                return example[0][k].status_name;
            })
```

```js
var example = [{
  "logged": {
    "status": 0,
    "status_name": "Logged",
    "hours": 23 // to the hours array
  },
  "pending": {
    "status": 3,
    "status_name": "Pending",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 0,
      "count": 0
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 6, // to the hours array
      "count": 1
    }
  },
  "denied": {
    "status": 4,
    "status_name": "Denied",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 0,
      "count": 0
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 0, // to the hours array
      "count": 0
    }
  },
  "approved": {
    "status": 2,
    "status_name": "Approved",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 4.5,
      "count": 1
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 0, // to the hours array
      "count": 0
    }
  }
}];

var hours = [];
var statusNames = Object.keys(example[0]).map(function(k) {
  hours.push(example[0][k].hours || example[0][k].verification.hours || 0);
  return example[0][k].status_name;
})

console.log(hours, statusNames)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the array and over the keys, check if the property exist and include the wanted part into the arrays.

```js
var example = [{ "logged": { "status": 0, "status_name": "Logged", "hours": 23 }, "pending": { "status": 3, "status_name": "Pending", "contribution": { "hours": 0, "count": 0 }, "verification": { "hours": 6, "count": 1 } }, "denied": { "status": 4, "status_name": "Denied", "contribution": { "hours": 0, "count": 0 }, "verification": { "hours": 0, "count": 0 } }, "approved": { "status": 2, "status_name": "Approved", "contribution": { "hours": 4.5, "count": 1 }, "verification": { "hours": 0, "count": 0 } } }],
    statusNames = [],
    hours = [];

example.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if ('hours' in o[k]) {
            statusNames.push(k);
            hours.push(o[k].hours);
            return;
        }
        if ('verification' in o[k]) {
            statusNames.push(k);
            hours.push(o[k].verification.hours);
        }
    });
});
console.log(statusNames);
console.log(hours);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use Array.prototype.reduce to filter the information you need.

```js
var example = [{
  "logged": {
    "status": 0,
    "status_name": "Logged",
    "hours": 23 // to the hours array
  },
  "pending": {
    "status": 3,
    "status_name": "Pending",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 0,
      "count": 0
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 6, // to the hours array
      "count": 1
    }
  },
  "denied": {
    "status": 4,
    "status_name": "Denied",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 0,
      "count": 0
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 0, // to the hours array
      "count": 0
    }
  },
  "approved": {
    "status": 2,
    "status_name": "Approved",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 4.5,
      "count": 1
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 0, // to the hours array
      "count": 0
    }
  }
}]

var statusNames = example.reduce(function(prevVal, currVal) {
  for(var key in currVal) {
    if(!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(currVal, key)) continue

    if(currVal[key].status_name) {
      prevVal.push(currVal[key].status_name)
    }
   
  }
  return prevVal
}, [])


console.log(statusNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
// get all of the objects keys
var statusNames = Object.keys(example);
var hours = [];

// get all of the hours
example.forEach( function(item, idx){
    idx === 0 ? hours.push(item.hours) : false; // because the hours in your first object is not nested.
    idx > 0 ? hours.push(item.verification.hours) : false; // gets all of the nested hours.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `for (var key in example[0])` for iteration through each key.

Then push the values in respective arrays

`statusNames.push(key);
hours.push(example[0][key]["hours"] || example[0][key]["verification"]["hours"] );`

```js
var  statusNames = [];
   var hours = [];
   
var example = [{
  "logged": {
    "status": 0,
    "status_name": "Logged",
    "hours": 23 // to the hours array
  },
  "pending": {
    "status": 3,
    "status_name": "Pending",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 0,
      "count": 0
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 6, // to the hours array
      "count": 1
    }
  },
  "denied": {
    "status": 4,
    "status_name": "Denied",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 0,
      "count": 0
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 0, // to the hours array
      "count": 0
    }
  },
  "approved": {
    "status": 2,
    "status_name": "Approved",
    "contribution": {
      "hours": 4.5,
      "count": 1
    },
    "verification": {
      "hours": 0, // to the hours array
      "count": 0
    }
  }
}];


for (var key in example[0]) {
      statusNames.push(key);
   hours.push(example[0][key]["hours"] || example[0][key]["verification"]["hours"] );
     
}
console.log(statusNames);
console.log(hours);
```